# UITextField in UIPopoverController and hiding keyboard with tap outside of popover

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uipopovercontroller

I have a `UITextField` in a `UIPopoverController`. When the user inputs data, I want him to be able to tap the screen anywhere outside of the popover to hide the keyboard.

Before, I would add a `UIControl` to a `UIView` to detect the tap and hide it, but I don't think this work in this situation.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't thing you need any handling for resigning TextField as such, as soon as popover will dismiss the Keyboard should resign, or you can try handle delegate methods of popover like `popoverControllerDidDismissPopover`

Comment: Yep, you are absolutely correct. But I should have mentioned I am not allowing the popover to dismiss on tap outside of it.

Comment: I think you should handle in `popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover` delegate function, you must be returning there NO, before just returning resign textfield.

Comment: Ok, the textField's delegate is set to a UITableViewController in the popover. So I have a class Object which is the popover's delegate. In the popover I have a class List. In list is the textfield and List is its delegate. I would have to use a `NSNotification` to tell the textfield to resign firstResponse.